# CF - ORM Data Source - Declared After Login?

Tags: mysql, orm, coldfusion, datasource

**Update: Question Answered**

But, since I don't know how to 'delete' or 'void' a question ...

**[ Original question ]**

I have a ColdFusion application using ORM that services different companies. So I need to change the ORM data source after they login (identify themselves). I'm currently using this code:

```
    <cfset this.datasource = SESSION.USER.DBSOURCE>
```

No this is created after login - after the application starts.  However, as far as I know the ORM data source needs to be declared prior to any login.

I am not sure I phrased this question correctly, but can anyone help with this?

Comment: If your question has been answered, you can submit the answer yourself and accept it. :)

Comment: Perhaps what you are really asking is: How do I connect to a db based on the db that the user should be using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

True: CF ORM DSN needs to be declared prior to any login.